# Defining element initialization order when constructing std::tuple

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, tuples, order-of-execution

I would like to store the initialization values for elements in a tuple inside a separate tuple, so that I can use the same values as a preset for other tuples of the respective type.

It is very important to my program that the constructors of the tuple elements are called in left-to-right order (otherwise it would at best turn out very confusing).

Here is a simplified version of my program:

```
#include <tuple>

// Elements are the end points of a Widget hierarchy
struct Element
{
    using initer_t = int;
    Element( const initer_t pIniter )
        :data{ pIniter }
    {
        printf("Creating %i\n", data);
    }
    const initer_t data;
};

// A Widget class stores any number of Elements and/or other Widget instances
template<typename... Elems>
    struct Widget
    {
        using initer_t = std::tuple<typename Elems::initer_t...>;
        Widget( const initer_t pIniter )
            :elements{ pIniter } 
        {}
        const std::tuple<Elems...> elements;
    };

int main()
{
    using Button = Widget<Element, Element>;
    using ButtonList = Widget<Button, Button, Element>;

    Button::initer_t basic_button_initer{ 0, 1 }; // presets for Buttons
    Button::initer_t other_button_initer{ 2, 3 }; 

    ButtonList::initer_t buttonlist_initer{ basic_button_initer, other_button_initer, 4 }; //a preset for a ButtonList

    ButtonList buttonlist{ buttonlist_initer };
    return 0;
}
```

So I am initializing the `std::tuple<Elems...> elements` member of `Widget<Elems...>` with a `std::tuple<typename Elems::initer_t...>` in `Widget<Elems...>`'s constructor initialization list. 
This is supposed to initialize each element of `elements` with its corresponding initialization value of the type defined by `initer_t` using the values in pIniter.
The `initer_t` type is a type for each member of a Widget hierarchy(for example a `Widget<typename...>` or an `Element`), which is the type that the hierarchy member should be initialized with. 
But the order in which this happens is right-to-left, while I need it in left-to-right.

The output of the program is

```
Creating 4
Creating 3
Creating 2
Creating 1
Creating 0
```

But I want to reverse this order.

How can I do this in this case?

Comment: Even this order is not guaranteed.

Comment: from g++ I get "4 3 2 1 0", from clang++ "0 1 2 3 4"

Comment: I just compiled it with clang and clang++ and I get "4 3 2 1 0" ...

Comment: Why exactly do you need a specific order? Is it for logging?

Comment: In my actual implementation the Widget class is used for GUI widgets. The Element class is actually a 2D Quad and this structure is supposed to organize these Quads in a modular hierarchy. The reason why they need to be initialized in order is that the Quads are rendered in the order in which they were created, meaning that Quads initialized later will be rendered on top of Quads initialized before. There are other ways to organize this but for the sake of simplicity and performance would really prefer to compose the Quads this way.

Comment: @stimulate "I just compiled it with clang" is not useful information, because what matters here is the implementation of `std::tuple`. So using Clang & libstdc++ will give the same result as GCC (because it uses the same `std::tuple`). Using Clang & libc++ will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in a solution, I came up with a way to control the initialization order and retain the constness of `elements`:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Elems>
    struct construct 
    {
        template<size_t... Ns, typename Head, typename... Rest>
            static constexpr const std::tuple<Rest...> 
                drop_head_impl( const std::index_sequence<Ns...> ns, 
                    const std::tuple<Head, Rest...> tup )
            {
                return std::tuple<Rest...>( std::get<Ns + 1u>( tup )... );
            }

        template<typename Head, typename... Rest>
            static constexpr const std::tuple<Rest...> 
                drop_head( const std::tuple<Head, Rest...> tup )
            {
                return drop_head_impl( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Rest)>(), tup );
            }

        template<typename Head>
            static constexpr const std::tuple<Head> 
                func_impl( const std::tuple<typename Head::initer_t> initer )
            {
                return  std::tuple<Head>( { std::get<0>( initer ) } ); 
            }

        template<typename Head, typename Next, typename... Rest>
            static constexpr const std::tuple<Head, Next, Rest...> 
                func_impl( const std::tuple<typename Head::initer_t, typename Next::initer_t, typename Rest::initer_t...> initer )
            {
                std::tuple<Head> head( { std::get<0>( initer ) } ); 
                return std::tuple_cat( head, func_impl<Next, Rest...>( drop_head(initer) ) );
            }

        static constexpr const std::tuple<Elems...> 
            func( const std::tuple<typename Elems::initer_t...> initer )
        {
            return func_impl<Elems...>( initer );
        }
    };

// Elements are the end points of a Widget hierarchy
struct Element
{
    using initer_t = int;
    Element( const initer_t pIniter )
        :data{ pIniter }
    {
        printf( "Creating %i\n", data );
    }
    const initer_t data;
};

// A Widget class stores any number of Elements and/or other Widget instances
template<typename... Elems>
    struct Widget
    {
        using initer_t = std::tuple<typename Elems::initer_t...>;
        Widget( const initer_t pIniter )
            :elements( construct<Elems...>::func( pIniter ) ) 
        {}
        const std::tuple<Elems...> elements;
    };

int main()
{
    using Button = Widget<Element, Element>;
    using ButtonList = Widget<Button, Button, Element>;

    Button::initer_t basic_button_initer{ 0, 1 }; // presets for Buttons
    Button::initer_t other_button_initer{ 2, 3 }; 

    ButtonList::initer_t buttonlist_initer{ basic_button_initer, other_button_initer, 4 }; //a preset for a ButtonList

    ButtonList buttonlist{ buttonlist_initer };
    return 0;
}
```

The `construct` structure takes the tuple of `initer_t`s (initer), constructs a tuple containing the first element of `Elems...` using the first element of initer, then drops the first element of initer and passes the remaining tuple to itself, which causes a tuple with the next element of `Elems...` to be constructed using the next element in initer. This recursion is stopped by an overload of `func_impl` for a tuple with one element which simply constructs that element from its `initer_t` in a tuple and returns it. This single-element tuple gets concatenated to the tuple with the previous element, the result gets returned to the higher level and is concatenated to the single-element tuple there and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement in the standard for the order of `std::tuple` member initialisation, I am afraid.

You can iterate over a `tuple` in a specific order though, e.g.:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/for_each.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_tuple(true, 42, 3.14, "abc");
    boost::fusion::for_each(a, [](auto& value) {
            std::cout << value << '\n';
        });
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
42
3.14
abc
```

Comment: :( So this means I have to retreat to initializing each member one by one, which means I cant make `elements` const, which makes this entire thing a lot less elegant and performant..? Kind of a let-down from C++...